# For-loop exeeds condition limit in C

Tags: c, for-loop

At my output everthing is fine except that it takes a NULL character to be right, what's is wrong is that after the for-loop checking the condition between the array `*ans[]={"zero","one","two"};` and the `inp` : the last number of `sel` is `2` and with my condition still true it executes `sel++` which makes the `sel = 3` which is my limit that causes NULL input to be accepted. **How would I restrict** `sel` **in my for-loop from exeeding it's limit?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    char    inp[256]={0},
            *ans[]={"zero","one","two"};
    int     sel,
            ans_cnt=sizeof(ans)/sizeof(ans[0]); // Equals to 3
    do{
        clrscr();
        printf("Enter Any:\n\"zero\" or \n\"one\"  or \n\"three\": ");
        gets(inp);
        for(sel=0;sel<ans_cnt && strcmp(inp,ans[sel]);sel++);
        }
    while(strcmp(inp,ans[sel]));
    printf("Valid Answer!");
    getch();
    }
```

Comment: Don't use the `gets` function, it has been deprecated for a very long time. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Ok ok. here (and stop using `gets()`) : `while(sel == ans_cnt);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if the string is not found in the inner `for` loop, then `sel` will be `3`. This causes `ans` in the following `while` condition to be indexed out of bounds.

This can be solved by changing the `while` condition to just check for that:

```
while (sel == ans_cnt);
```

Comment: Also I have already explain it but *out of bounds* term is better

Comment: @Daniel Should it be? It's not in your `ans` array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of it you can use break.

```
while ( TRUE ) {
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter Any:\n\"zero\" or \n\"one\"  or \n\"three\": ");
  gets(inp);
  for(sel=0;sel<ans_cnt && strcmp(inp,ans[sel]);sel++);
  if ( sel < 3 ) // It means for loop was ended before the sel < ans_cnt condition
    break;
}
```

Comment: Many have suggested not to use `while` loop only, cause my original code have multiple conditions...

Comment: @Daniel you still can use break with do...while();